# Java Compiler for Less CSS?

Tags: java, css, less

I am looking for Java-based Less CSS compilers.
On Github, I have stumbled across

- lesscss4j
- lesscss-java

Both are from the same developer. Unfortunately I cannot quite figure out the difference between them.

Can somebody tell me?
Which other compilers do you know?

Comment: Look inside PlayFramework 2, there is a Less compiler included.

Comment: Looks to me like lesscss4j was the old name for the project, lesscss-java the new name.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Meanwhile I got an answer from the developer who confirmed that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[LESS Engine](https://github.com/asual/lesscss-engine) wraps the javascript compiler in a straight-forward Java interface.

I haven't used lesscss-java, so I can't comment on relative quality, but in the small tasks I've needed, I've had no complaints with Less Engine.

Comment: I've been using it, and it worked pretty well. The lesscss-maven-plugin did not work very well for me, so I made a FileWatcher with this that compiles the files when something changes.

Answer (score 8):

[The Official LESS CSS Compiler for Java](https://github.com/marceloverdijk/lesscss-java) is pretty nice, too. It's in Maven Central, is thread safe (so performance is pretty good), and it's got an easy to use interface.

Comment: How is this compiler more official than the LESS Engine @codelark mentions in his answer? I don't so neither linked on http://lesscss.org/.

Answer (score 4):

[JLessC](https://github.com/i-net-software/jlessc) is an alternative less compiler. It is pure Java and does not use any JavaScript engine. The main target is use together with Bootstrap. It is very fast.

Answer (score 2):

[lesscss4j](https://github.com/localmatters/lesscss4j) is a Java compiler, written with ANTLR. While this will be faster, the problem is that you need to synchronise it with the official lesscss compiler which is in javascript. This project hasn't been touched for 2 years. [Lesscss-java](https://github.com/marceloverdijk/lesscss-java) is a wrapper around the official compiler and is running in Rhino JS engine. It used by the popular [Lesscss-maven-plugin](https://github.com/marceloverdijk/lesscss-maven-plugin).

Answer (score 2):

[LessCSS Compiler](http://lesscss-compiler.projects.gabrys.biz/) - compatible with version [1.7.5](https://github.com/less/less.js/releases/tag/v1.7.5). The library is based on the official [Less](http://lesscss.org/) JavaScript compiler adapted to the [Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino) engine.

It supports sources located at:

- local drives
- protocols:

  - HTTP and HTTPS
  - FTP (requires [Apache Commons Net](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/) library in the class path)
    & class path (prefix `classpath://`)
  - custom - defined by programmers (see [FileSystem](http://lesscss-compiler.projects.gabrys.biz/2.0.0/apidocs/index.html?biz/gabrys/lesscss/compiler2/filesystem/FileSystem.html))

The library requires Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with [atlassian](http://atlassian.com) plugins and in addition to the already mentioned [lesscss-maven-plugin](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22lesscss-maven-plugin%22) you might also have a look at a (non-open-sourced) derivate from atlassian repository https://maven.atlassian.com/content/repositories/atlassian-public

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.atlassian.lesscss</groupId>
    <artifactId>lesscss-maven-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
```