# Is all lesscss libraries for java dead?

Tags: java, less

actually i'm using less4j project for real time compile of less files in my java project.

The problem is that we have 41Mb of resident memory after compiling, and cannot be freed. GitHub project members does not reply to issues from 6 months almost.

So we are looking for other java libs, but the only one is from 2014 (official less compiler ...).

Are all lesscss libraries for java abandoned? 
Some suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Compiler for Less CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9739724/java-compiler-for-less-css)

Answer (score 1):

You can check my library:

[LessCSS Compiler](http://lesscss-compiler.projects.gabrys.biz/) - compatible with version [1.7.5](https://github.com/less/less.js/releases/tag/v1.7.5). The library is based on the official [Less](http://lesscss.org/) JavaScript compiler adapted to the [Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino) engine.

It supports sources located at:

- local drives
- protocols:

  - HTTP and HTTPS
  - FTP (requires [Apache Commons Net](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/) library in the class path)
    & class path (prefix `classpath://`)
  - custom - defined by programmers (see [FileSystem](http://lesscss-compiler.projects.gabrys.biz/2.0.0/apidocs/index.html?biz/gabrys/lesscss/compiler2/filesystem/FileSystem.html))

The library requires Java 8.

There are also some other libraries: [Java Compiler for Less CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9739724/4944847)